# How to Implement Undo for Treeview

Tags: c#

I am working in windows application. My problem is..

I have treeview & a textbox control in the form.  For each node text present in the textbox is saving in a database.

Currently my program is working like this.
1) Treeview_BeforeSelect() : in this method i have written the code to save the textbox data in a database.
2) Treeview_AfterSelect() : in this method i have written the code to get the data from the database & display it in a textbox.

Now i have to implement Undo for this treeview.  Please suggest any ideas regarding this.

Comment: What kind of operations do you need to undo?

Comment: Thanks Lasse..  The Operations i need to do are Text, Attachments & Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a simple as adding a time stamp field everytime you persist your data to the database? Every time you persist the treeview, you need to insert a new row and increment a version. If you want to undo, all you need to do is get the previous version.

Comment: Thanks Darvindave,    My treeview nodes contains attachments(picture/Excel files etc) & also the text.. I need to Undo the whole.